# Regex pattern to extract domain name, video url and video id from a string containing youtube/vimeo url with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, preg-match-all, vimeo

I need a regex or php preg_match function that should extract youtube/vimeo url and the video provider/domain name like (vimeo/youtube) from a string containing a video url.

And from the extracted video url of string, i need to find the exact video id.

The regex should graph Video ID from the below url also,

1. Youtube
   https://youtube.googleapis.com/v/jGyZDgpv_Hk
2. vimeo
   https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/167414855

Thanks, i am working on the solution. I will post as an answer if i find it.

Comment: 404 question not found

Comment: @VigneshChinnaiyan, this looks like an answer. What's the question?

Comment: @jkdev Sorry for posting my answer as like a question, i was referring stackoverflow and other websites for this exact answer. I was unable to find an answer, so i just worked on solution. To help others who got this like doubt can refer this. That's why i posted as a new question.

Comment: People like to do that sometimes. You're allowed to post a question, and then post an answer on your own question, in order to share your knowledge with others. I've done that too ;)

Comment: @jkdev, thanks for your support buddy, i have altered the question section, and i have posted my answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sample_text = "Cieker is the largest talentize social and professional networking website, you can view it on https://www.cieker.com and the about video is on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGyZDgpv_Hk";
```

***// Function to return video url from string***

```
  function extract($html)
  {

  $regex = '/(http:|https:|)\/\/(player.|www.)?(vimeo\.com|youtu(be\.com|\.be|be\.googleapis\.com))\/(video\/|embed\/|channels\/(?:\w+\/)|watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/';

  preg_match_all($regex, $html, $match);

  $matched = array_unique($match[0]);

  usort($matched, function($a, $b) 

  {

      return strlen($b) - strlen($a);

  });

  return $matched;

}
```

***// calls function, returns the youtube or vimeo url from a string.***

```
$check_extract = extract($sample_url );
```

***// function to find the video provider name.***

```
function videoType($url) {

if (strpos($url, 'youtu') > 0)
{

  return 'youtube';

} 
else if (strpos($url, 'vimeo') > 0) 
{

  return 'vimeo';

} 
else 
{

  return 'unknown';

}

}
```

***// calls function, has extracted url as a parameter.***

```
$provider = videoType($check_extract[0]);
```

***// The following regex will extract the video id from above extracted youtube url.***

```
if($provider=="youtube")

{
preg_match("/^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'>]+)/",$check_extract[0], $matches);?>
$id =$matches[1];

}

else if($provider=="vimeo")

{

preg_match("/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(player\.)?vimeo\.com\/([a-z]*\/)*([0-9]{6,11})[?]?.*/",$check_extract[0], $output_array);?>

$id =$output_array[5];

}
```

***// this will get video id of youtube/vimeo.***

```
$video_id = $id;
```

[image]